# exploring interactions with multiple factors using lmer and emmeans

Tags: lme4-nlme, lsmeans

```
data <- data.frame(ID=rep(seq(1,9),each=3), group=rep(c("G1","G2","G3"),each=9), valence=rep(c("negative","positive","neutral"),times=9), y=c(12,55,14,16,65,16,17,64,22,4,16,18,5,17,19,8,12,12,54,55,43,66,43,48,13,22,33))
```

With these data I get a significant `group:valence` interaction. I would like to look into this interaction further and check in what type of `valence` there are differences between the groups (for example, are the groups significantly different in negative valence only?).

I know I can get the pairwise comparisons with `emmeans`, but I think I should first determine what valence types are worth exploring before doing the pairwise comparisons.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at some of the vignettes in the emmeans package. The one on "basics" for fundamental concepts and "interactions" for your situation. Maybe some others as needed. There is an index of vignette topics as well.

Comment: @RussLenth Thank you for you comment. Yes, I had actually gone through those vignettes before posting, but somehow missed the `joint_tests` function, which is what I should use right? I have two additional questions: if I do `m <- lmer(y ~ group*valence + (1|ID), data=data)` and then `joint_tests(m, by="group")` 1) do I need to correct for multiple tests (in this example 3). 2) do I have to use type III, can I not select the type as with the anova function: `anova(m, type=2)`?

Comment: I'd just do an interaction plot myself and decide from there, but joint_tests will gove you omnibus tests if that's what you want. Type 2 tests are based on model comparisons and we have only one model actually fitted, so joint_tests is not terribly well suited for those. That said, adding `submodel = "type2"` will sort of do that. With lmer models, it is only approximate. See the help files for more info.

Comment: Thanks @RussLenth, that was very informative. Regarding the multiple comparisons correction, you're saying I should simply plot emmip(m, valence~group) and check which contrasts I should run? I'm concerned reviewers will accuse me of cherry-picking to get away having to correct for fewer tests. For example, I see that only positive valence differs from negative in G1. Should I test the significance of this effect alone based on this observation?

Comment: I was saying that from an exploratory point of view - and there is value in visualizing effects. But you're right, that does encourage cherry-picking, and you need to do things that are defensible in reviewers' eyes.

Comment: That's why I thought whether I should instead correct for the three omnibus tests that `joint_tests(m, by="group")` does. If `valence` is only significant for `G1`, then I could then just compare `valence` types in this group. The question is whether correcting these omnibus tests are really necessary from a statistical point of view.

Comment: @RussLenth, I tried to correct for multiple comparisons with `emm <- emmeans(m, pairwise~group|valence)` and then `test(emm$contrasts, joint=TRUE, adjust="bonferroni")` but the p.value is exactly the same as with `adjust="none"`. I guess p.value adjustment cannot be made this way?

Comment: I also tried using `summary(by=NULL)` but since the output of `test()` isn't an `emmGrid` object, it doesn't work...

Comment: If you have only one comparison, then there is no multiplicity to adjust for, and every adjustment method yields the same result. By default, contrast() adjusts each by group separately. If you want them combined, then you have to do test(my.result, by = NULL)

Comment: Don't call test() until the very, very end. CON = contrast(...), test(CON, by = NULL)